Logical Implication between pairs of Non-negative Continuous or Integer Variables
Say for instance, I have two non-negative continuous or integer variables, $x$, $y$, I would like to ask about the constraints representing the following implications
i) $x\gt 0 \iff y \gt 0$
ii) $x = 0 \iff y = 0$

The two implications i) and ii) are equivalent, and you can linearize them as follows.  Assume $0\le x \le M$ and $0\le y \le M$, let $\epsilon$ be a small positive constant tolerance, introduce binary decision variable $z$, and impose linear big-M constraints
\begin{align}
\epsilon z \le x \le M z \tag1\label1\\
\epsilon z \le y \le M z \tag2\label2
\end{align}
If $x$ and $y$ are integer variables, you can take $\epsilon=1$.
To check that these constraints enforce $x>0 \implies y>0$, note that \eqref{1} enforces $x>0 \implies z=1$ and \eqref{2} enforces $z=1 \implies y \ge \epsilon$.  The other checks are similar.

May I ask if what would need to be changed if the UB of y is set to be, for instance, a non-negative real or integer with upper bound, N? Thanks!

In that case, just change $M$ to $N$ in \eqref{2}.

Thank you! As a side note, I am able to handle pure logical constraints as these are covered in certain standard text books. To the best of my knowledge, there is, however, inadequate, if not, anemic coverage on such mixed constraints. If I may ask, could you share certain standard procedures or material on this. I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you again!
