Implication linking triplets of non-negative real or integer variables
Say for instance, I have a triplet of non-negative continuous or integer variables, $x$, $y$, $z$, where $z$ can be replaced by a non-negative continuous or integer.
I would like to ask about the constraints representing the following implications:
i) $x=0 \iff y=0$
ii) $x\gt 0 \iff y=z$
iii) $x=0 \iff y=0$ and $x\gt 0 \iff y=z$

i) was already answered here: https://or.stackexchange.com/a/12403/500

Just to confirm if i want z to be be any number say 10, with reference to the link, can I  let epsilon=10 and M=10?

Not sure what you mean.  In the linked answer, $z$ is a binary variable ($0$ or $1$).

I meant z in this current question which is equal to epsilon or M in  https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/12402/logical-implication-between-pairs-of-non-negative-continuous-or-integer-variable/

Part i) was already answered here: https://or.stackexchange.com/a/12403/500
For part ii), let $\bar{x}$, $\bar{y}$, and $\bar{z}$ be constant upper bounds on $x,y,z$, respectively.  Let $\epsilon$ be a small positive constant tolerance, introduce binary decision variables $w_i$, and impose linear big-M constraints
\begin{align}
w_1 + w_2 + w_3 &= 1 \tag1\label1 \\
0w_1 + \epsilon w_2 + 0w_3 \le x &\le 0w_1 + \bar{x} w_2 + 0w_3 \tag2\label2 \\
(0-\bar{z}) w_1 + 0w_2 + \epsilon w_3 \le y-z &\le -\epsilon w_1 + 0w_2 + (\bar{y}-0)w_3 \tag3\label3
\end{align}
To see that this works, just check the three cases for $w_i$.  For example, if $w_1=1$, then $0 \le x \le 0$ and $-\bar{z} \le y - z \le -\epsilon$.  That is, $x=0$ and $y<z$.
For part iii), replace \eqref{3} with
\begin{align}
0w_1 + \epsilon w_2 + 0w_3 \le y &\le 0w_1 + \bar{y} w_2 + 0w_3 \tag4\label4 \\
(0-\bar{z}) w_1 + 0w_2 + \epsilon w_3 \le y-z &\le -\epsilon w_1 + 0w_2 + (0-0)w_3 \tag5\label5
\end{align}
If $x,y,z$ are integer variables, you can take $\epsilon=1$.
